# How to convert a column of English and Arabic values to ID's

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns filled with values written in Arabic and English. This tends to give some trouble in my tables, because of the fact English is written from left to right and Arabic from right to left. So I want to give each unique value in a certain column his own ID.

Take in consideration that the dataset has more than 300k rows and over 100 unique values.

```
dd$column: 

احتراق
تجاوز سرعة
تفحيط
تجاوز سرعة
تجاوز سرعة
تفحيط
```

Which I want to convert to something like this:

```
dd$column:

ID_1
ID_2
ID_4
ID_2
ID_2
ID_4
```

So basically I have a column with an x amount of unique values. I assign to every unique value an ID. Next, I replace every value in said column by the ID. Although, I also have to come up with something that links the ID's to the actual words so I can retrace which ID is which word. i.e. Change the ID's back to the original value.

Answer (score 1):

```
sub("arab","ID",dd$column)
[1] "ID_1" "ID_2" "ID_4" "ID_2" "ID_2" "ID_4"

dd$column = sub("arab","ID",dd$column)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it wouldn't work in this case. I have columns of more than 300k rows so by assigning 'hand-written' names would take quite some time. I will edit my openingpost.

Comment: You can generalise that to fit any word ... `sub('.*_', 'ID_', dd$column)`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clearly. the '_' part is not actually in the data. I edited the post with some actual values

Answer (score 0):

I think using data table might work.

```
> library(data.table)
> names = data.frame("names" = c("John","James", "John", "Tom", "Jane", "Tom"))
> setDT(names)
> names[ , grp := .GRP, by = list(names)]
> names[ , grp := paste("ID_", grp)]
>> print (names)
   names    grp
   John    ID_ 1
   James   ID_ 2
   John    ID_ 1
   Tom     ID_ 3
   Jane    ID_ 4
   Tom     ID_ 3
```